# Star rating along a shape of semi-circle

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been struggling to create a start rating that takes a shape of semi-circle like the below image. the progress section is no problem. The problem is that I need to place 10 strokes of star shape along the path of the progress. The stars will fill by the progress background color, so there is no need to change the stars with different progress. the stars are static.

[image]

Any advice on how to do this will be highly appreciated.

This is what I achieved so far:

[image]

Comment: @Huangism OP probably would need something dynamic

Comment: worst case scenario, you could always position the stars 1 by 1

Comment: Since you've already achieved the arc, combine it with one of these techniques: https://uicookies.com/star-rating-css/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this for the stars, you would have to position them correctly so they fit in the strip. If you use any kind of css pre-processer, you can do the calculation in a function.

This is just a rough idea to show you it can be used. You would need to adjust the position and possibly the angles to fit your arc. These stars are using html entities which you can replace with an image(need background transparency) if you want

```css
.crescent {
  border-top-left-radius: 50%;
  border-top-right-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 222px;
  width: 222px;
}
.stars {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 97px;
  transform: rotate(-2deg);
}
.stars div {
  font: 26px Monaco, MonoSpace;
  height: 110px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transform-origin: bottom center;
}
.stars :nth-child(1) {
  transform: rotate(-10deg);
}
.stars :nth-child(2) {
  transform: rotate(-30deg);
}
.stars :nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotate(-50deg);
}
.stars :nth-child(4) {
  transform: rotate(-70deg);
}
.stars :nth-child(5) {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
.stars :nth-child(6) {
  transform: rotate(10deg);
}
.stars :nth-child(7) {
  transform: rotate(30deg);
}
.stars :nth-child(8) {
  transform: rotate(50deg);
}
.stars :nth-child(9) {
  transform: rotate(70deg);
}
.stars :nth-child(10) {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="crescent">
  <div class="stars">
    <div>&#9734;</div>
    <div>&#9734;</div>
    <div>&#9734;</div>
    <div>&#9734;</div>
    <div>&#9734;</div>
    <div>&#9734;</div>
    <div>&#9734;</div>
    <div>&#9734;</div>
    <div>&#9734;</div>
    <div>&#9734;</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice job. It is done. But a small problem is when I press ctrl + p the stars will jump to the right a little bit. I think it would be great to render it on server and convert it to static image. Is it the proper way to do it?

Comment: For printing, your browser(depending on what browser) probably created a scrollbar somewhere which causes the jump. Your whole page probably jumps. As for the static image, this is up to you, whatever way you think is the easiest way to implement then do that. Any suggestion on this would be an opinion. My personal opinion is making the stars a svg image so it can scaled easily

Comment: Nice idea thanks again.